# Hibernate 4 Save not working

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm new to hibernate 4 and I'm having some problem while saving a object using *save(Object)* method. My mapping files generated using reverse engineering are give below.

Event.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "event")
public class Event implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer eventId;
private Set<EventCategory> eventCategories = new HashSet<EventCategory>(0);

public Event() {
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "EVENT_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getEventId() {
    return this.eventId;
}

public void setEventId(Integer eventId) {
    this.eventId = eventId;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "event")
public Set<EventCategory> getEventCategories() {
    return this.eventCategories;
}
public void setEventCategories(Set<EventCategory> eventCategories) {
    this.eventCategories = eventCategories;
}

}
```

category.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer categoryId;
private Set<EventCategory> eventCategories = new HashSet<EventCategory>(0);

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "CATEGORY_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getCategoryId() {
    return this.categoryId;
}

public void setCategoryId(Integer categoryId) {
    this.categoryId = categoryId;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "category")
public Set<EventCategory> getEventCategories() {
    return this.eventCategories;
}

public void setEventCategories(Set<EventCategory> eventCategories) {
    this.eventCategories = eventCategories;
}

}
```

EventCategory.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "event_category")
public class EventCategory implements java.io.Serializable {

private EventCategoryId id;
private Event event;
private Category category;

public EventCategory() {
}

public EventCategory(EventCategoryId id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public EventCategory(EventCategoryId id, Event event, Category category) {
    this.id = id;
    this.event = event;
    this.category = category;
}

@EmbeddedId
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "eventId", column = @Column(name = "EVENT_ID")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "categoryId", column = @Column(name = "CATEGORY_ID")) })
public EventCategoryId getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(EventCategoryId id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "EVENT_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public Event getEvent() {
    return this.event;
}

public void setEvent(Event event) {
    this.event = event;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public Category getCategory() {
    return this.category;
}

public void setCategory(Category category) {
    this.category = category;
}

}
```

All these files are generated using hbm2java (reverse engineering). But i couldn't able to save values using the below code. And also I'm not getting any exception while running this piece of code.

```
EventCategory eventCategory = new EventCategory();
eventCategory.setEvent(event);
eventCategory.setCategory(category);
eventCategory.setId(eventCategoryId);
getSession().save( eventCategory );
```

Please help me to resolve my problem

Comment: So, what's the problem? Nothing appears in the database? Have you enclosed this code in a transaction, that you commit at the end?

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for your comment. Yes you are correct. It worked after using the Transaction as given in below post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a transaction.

```
EventCategory eventCategory = new EventCategory();
eventCategory.setEvent(event);
eventCategory.setCategory(category);
eventCategory.setId(eventCategoryId);

Session session = getSession();
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
session.save( eventCategory );
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: you are correct. After enclosing in Transaction it is working fine. But my doubt is I'm able to save other objects(like event) without any transaction. why i'm need to use transaction for this object alone. I used the below code to save event object and it got save in DB.    int eventID = (Integer) getSession().save(event);

Comment: Is the other code running in a managed environment? CMT/EJB? With CMT, the transaction is handled automatically in the session bean (even rollback). So the transaction code isn't necessary in that situation.

Comment: Are you using spring? Does your Event object have an @Transactional annotation that your EventCategory is missing?

Comment: yes I'm using spring and I'm not using EJB/CMT. and also no @Transactional is present in Event class.